# Customizing MOG2 algorithm

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I need to customize the MOG2 algorithm in OpenCV without editing the code. 
I need to:

- Give much weight for some parts of the new frame.
- Mask some parts of the new frame so it will not affect the process.

My goal is to get the background at the end of the stream. I do not care about the moving objects.

Is this possible? How (any small clue is enough)?

Comment: Do you just want to get the stable background and not the moving object? If yes it means you want to do some thing like inpainting for the detected moving object so the MOG2 will only model the background?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani Yes I just want the background. Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Run your caption and find the median value for each pixel lets call this medianBackground. In the second time first run MOG2 to get the mask of moving parts than replace in the original frame the moving parts with the median value of the background and run MOG2 again with the inpainted frame. There is alot of things to take care of but tell me what you think